# How do I create a new dataframe in R based on the quantiles of an existing dataframe?

Tags: r, filter, quantile

I have a dataframe(all_trips_v2) that includes a column for ride_length in seconds.  I used the summary function and determined there are a large number of ride_length observations that are too long and some that are too short.

```
summary(all_trips_v2$ride_length)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
    0     377     670    1217    1212 2946429
```

I used the quantile function to find out where the data starts and stops making sense.

```
quantiles_v2 <- quantile(all_trips_v2$ride_length,probs = seq(0,1,1/40))
quantiles_v2
```

From the results I want to create a new dataframe(all_trips_v3) that filters out the values below the 5% quantile and above the 97.5% quantile.  The ride_length variable is of the type "numeric".

I've tried to filter out the data quantile less than 5% and greater than 97.5%

```
all_trips_v3 <- all_trips_v2 %>%
  filter(all_trips_v2$ride_length > (quantiles_v2['5%'])) %>%
  filter(all_trips_v2$ride_length < (quantiles_v2['97.5%']))
```

But I get the following error

```
Error in `filter()`:
! Problem while computing `..1 = all_trips_v2$ride_length < 
(quantiles_v2["97.5%"])`.
✖ Input `..1` must be of size 5604422 or 1, not size 5900239.
```

Comment: Don't reference variables with `$` when piping via `%>%` - just `filter(ride_length > ...` will do it as `all_trips_v2` is passed to the `data=` argument of the `filter()` function already.

Comment: Why asymmetric, `'97.5%'` but `'5%'` instead of `'2.5%'`?

Comment: The ride length is the duration of each ride share trip.  The lower end is bike rides greater than 2 minutes.  At the upper end it jumps up from several hours to several weeks above 97.5%.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks ya'll. That worked with a simplified single filter statement.

```
all_trips_v3 <- all_trips_v2 %>% filter(ride_length > (quantiles_v2['5%']) & 
    ride_length < (quantiles_v2['97.5%']))
```